# Support UTF-8 in UniDAC( Firemonkey) for SQLite

Tags: delphi, sqlite, osx-leopard, firemonkey, unidac

Have next case:

My App gathering data from MacOS X Mail with UniDAC for FireMonkey, but received data not support UTF-8.

How can I set "Force Unicode" for UniDAC(SQLLite) by analogy with MyDAC components ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need set 
`Connection.SpecificOptions.Values['Unicode'] := True`